# Last night Windows Phone update 10 crashed my phone Lumia 540

Tags: windows-10-mobile, update, lumia-540

My device Lumia Dual 540 had an update about a year ago where Camera and Flashlight stopped working and I fed up trying to fix it :)

About 2 weeks ago there was a night update and suddenly, I found Camera and Flashlight working again. :O)

Yesterday, or say today early morning, there was an update (I said to myself, wow, phone is getting better and better and they are fixing things), after the that update, I wanted to check Flashlight, just in case, I found Windows crashed and restarted automatically, I found no Desktop at all only the menu is shown and this menu is missing lots of applications, moreover Camera and Light are not working anymore.
Do Microsoft guys make releases without testing?

**How to rollback my Windows Phone 10 to the previous release?**

Device: Lumia Dual 540
Version: 1607
OS Build: 10.0.14393.1715

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to roll back an update to a specific version.
I'd recommend doing a hard reset, that usually fixes a lot of problems related to updated.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing a hard reset. Please note this deletes all data from your phone and starts afresh.

> Press and hold <kbd>Volume Down</kbd> and <kbd>Power</kbd> at the same time until you feel a vibration (about 10–15 seconds). Ignore the `slide down to power off` screen.
>   When you feel the vibration, release the buttons, and then immediately press and hold the <kbd>volume down</kbd> button until you see a large exclamation mark.
>
> Once the exclamation mark appears, press the following four buttons in this order: <kbd>Volume Up</kbd>, <kbd>Volume Down</kbd>,<kbd>Power</kbd> and <kbd>Volume Down</kbd>. 
>   Your phone should now reset and restart itself. It might take a while for the reset to finish. You should see gears/cogs turning on the display, to signify the process. It might take a while to finish.

If this does not cut it, download the Windows Device Recovery Tool, and connect your phone to download and install the latest firmware for your phone. This should repair it, and is a fairly easy process although you lose all data which was on the phone. After that, you can then download any updates using your phone normally.